# Win32::IEAutomation will not click on links when IE >= 9

Tags: perl, web-scraping

On a modern setup (Windows 7 64-bit, IE 11, ActiveState Perl 5.16 64-bit), the `Click` method in [`Win32::IEAutomation`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aIEAutomation) (v0.5) does not seem to work.  Here is an example, lightly adapted from the documentation:

```
use Win32::IEAutomation;
my $ie = Win32::IEAutomation->new( visible => 1);
$ie->gotoURL('http://www.google.com');
$ie->getLink('linktext:', "About")->Click;
```

At this point, I should see the "About" page in IE.  But I still see Google's home page in IE, and I cannot use the `Content` method in Win32::IEAutomation to get the source of the "About" page.

I have the same problem on an older setup (Vista SP2 64-bit, IE 9, ActiveState Perl 5.10.1).   But the problem does not arise when I use a similar setup with IE8 instead of IE9.  The problem thus seems to lie with a difference between IE8 and subsequent IE versions.

Is there anything that I can do to get the example script working with more recent versions of IE?

Comment: @SinanÜnür - thank you.  I added those commands to the preamble, but they didn't change anything.  (No new warnings or errors.)  I also tried my example script with an older software setup and found that it worked -- I've added details to the post.

Answer (score 1):

[Win32::IEAutomation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aIEAutomation) is a thin wrapper around the various interfaces exposed by [InternetExplorer.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29) and [MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Therefore, I tried to replicate the problem by writing a script to do the navigation without using `Win32::IEAutomation`. Using the `click` method on a link did not initiate navigation whereas passing its `href` to `Navigate2` did.

The [click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method "*Simulates a click by causing the HTMLFrameSiteEvents::onclick event to fire*," meaning any `onClick` handlers defined on the page will be involved. I am not sure why specifically navigation is not being initiated.

However, the problem is not specific to Google's home page: I tried it with `example.com`, and invoking the `click` method on a link on that page did not initiate navigation either.

Here is the script I used as a testbed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Win32::OLE qw(EVENTS in valof);
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

my $url = 'https://www.google.com/';

my %event_handler = (
    DocumentComplete => \&onDocumentComplete,
);

my %page_handler = (
    'https://www.google.com/'
        => \&onPageGoogleHome,
    'https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/'
        => \&onPageGoogleAbout,
);

my $ie = Win32::OLE->new(
    "InternetExplorer.Application", sub { $_[0]->Quit }
);

Win32::OLE->WithEvents($ie, \&Event, 'DWebBrowserEvents2');

$ie->{Visible} = 1;
$ie->Navigate2($url);

Win32::OLE->MessageLoop;
Win32::OLE->SpinMessageLoop;

$ie->Quit;

sub Event {
    my ($ie, $event, @argv) = @_;

    if (exists $event_handler{$event}) {
        $event_handler{$event}->($ie, \@argv);
    }
    else {
        # unhandled event
    }
    return;
}

sub onDocumentComplete {
    my ($ie, $argv) = @_;
    my $url = valof($argv->[-1]);
    if (exists $page_handler{$url}) {
        $page_handler{$url}->($ie, $argv);
    }
    else {
        # unhandled page
    }
    return;
}

sub onPageGoogleHome {
    my ($ie, $argv) = @_;
    say "We are on Google's home page";
    my $links = $ie->Document->links;
    my $about_link;
    for my $link (in $links) {
        if ($link->innerText eq 'About') {
            say "Found 'About' link";
            $about_link = $link;
            last;
        }
    }
    if ($about_link) {
        # Doesn't work:
        # $about_link->click;

        $ie->Navigate2($about_link->href);
    }
    return;
}

sub onPageGoogleAbout {
    my ($ie, $argv) = @_;
    say "Yay, we are on the about page!";
    Win32::OLE->QuitMessageLoop;
    return;
}
```

Version information:

This is perl 5, version 19, subversion 12 (v5.19.12) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Internet Explorer 11

Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

Comment: Thank you very much.  My ultimate aim is to write a script that "clicks" on Javascript links (in pages that make ample use of AJAX), and to download the HTML that subsequently appears in the browser.  I haven't found any sort of Win32::OLE tutorial that speaks to exactly this goal.  But I think that I may be able to adapt your code so that it does what I need.  I'll soon try it.

Answer (score 1):

I observe the same faulty behavior with the `->Click()` in [`Strawberry Perl`](http://strawberryperl.com/) v5.18.2 and [`Win32::IEAutomation v0.5`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aIEAutomation) and IE v11.0.9600.17105.

My work around is to use the `gotoURL()` method directly.  This obviously would not work with javascript actions, but does for this particular example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::IEAutomation;

my $ie = Win32::IEAutomation->new( visible => 1);
$ie->gotoURL('http://www.google.com');

my $about = $ie->getLink('linktext:' => 'About')
    or die "Unable to find About";

# $about->Click(); # <--- does not work, using alternative method

$ie->gotoURL($about->linkUrl());
```

Comment: Thank you.  I offered the Google example because it was so simple, and because I hoped that solving it would solve my deeper problem.  You've identified that deeper problem: I would like to use Win32::IEAutomation to navigate Javascript links (on pages that make heavy use of AJAX), and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Consider using [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) for Javascript page automation.  I've heard much more success with that.